# TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parse_cols'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have use the following code to extract column from `AZ` to `CW`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/yze3laidhv7gl1x/Homework4.xlsx?dl=1'

changedate = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format = "%Y%m") 

df = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name = '49_Industry_Portfolios', header = 6, 
                   parse_cols = 'AZ:CW', index_col = 0, parse_dates = True, 
                   date_parser = changedate, na_values = [-99.99, -999])
print(df)
```

But it raises a `Traceback`, anyone could help me to fix this issue? Thanks.

Out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-671759d2c7d1>", line 17, in <module>
    date_parser = changedate, na_values = [-99.99, -999])

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parse_cols'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused because `parse_cols` is deprecated, use `usecols` instead.

```
df = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name = '49_Industry_Portfolios', header = 6, 
                   usecols = 'AZ:CW', index_col = 0, parse_dates = True, 
                   date_parser = changedate, na_values = [-99.99, -999])
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to use usecols for a given number (let say nb_cols) of first columns is:

`pd.read_excel(..., usecols=range(nb_cols), ...)`.

For PEP8 compliance, do not use space for keyword (named) arguments in function call

For start and end columns:

`pd.read_excel(..., usecols=range(start, end), ...)`.